# MySQL - How do I select data from a particular ID row?

Tags: mysql

this is very basic and I am just starting out! (I googled this but didn't see to get the right answer..)

OK, I know that when using php it is possible to execute SQL commands.

I would like to display data that just relates to the User ID.

When I created the database the first row was given the 'Auto Increment' label - and that is what I'd like to pull the data from... So, I'm thinking something like this will work....

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM name_of_table ID 4 ";
```

So the ALL data from the row of `ID 4` would be pulled -

How would I correctly write that?

Thanks

Comment: SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE ID=4

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE ID = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME= 'VALUE';